# Primary Decomposition: $G=G(p_1)\oplus...\oplus G(p_k)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Rotman's book proves that if $\text{exp}(G)=n=p_1^{e_1}...p_t^{e_t}$, we have $G=\sum_{j=1}^t\oplus_j G(p_j)$ where $G(p_j)=\{g| \: \text{ord}(g)=p_j^k \:\text{for some k}\}.$

In class, this theorem was slightly modified so that we sum over every prime such that there is a certain $x_i$ with $\text{ord}(x_i)=p_i$.

> Can I modify Rootman's result such that this other version holds?

I basically need to show I am summing over the same set of primes. I proved that the set of primes $q_i$ with $\text{ord}(x_i)=q_i$ for some $x_i$ is contained in Rotman's set of primes. I am having trouble with the other direction.

For the sake of completennes here is one inclusion. If $\text{ord}(x)=q$, we have by Rotman's result that $x=x_1+...+x_t\in \sum_j \oplus_j G(p_j)$ with some $x_j\not=0$.

Considering the fact that $qx=0$, we have $0=\sum_i q x_i$.Suppouse by way  of contradiction that $q\not =p_i$ for every $i$.Because the sum is direct and $qx_i\in G(p_i)$ (indeed, $G(p_i)$ is a subgroup), we have $qx_i=0$ for every $i$, in particular for $i=j$. Therefore $qx_j=0$ and $p_j|q$. Therefore $p_j=q$.

I still need to prove that for every $p_j$ dividing $\text{exp}(G)$ there is a certain $x$ with $\text{ord}(x)=p_j$

Comment: The exponent is the LCM of all the element orders. A prime divides an LCM of numbers iff it divides (at least) one of those numbers. So some element has order a multiple of that prime, and you can simply power that element to get an element of order exactly that prime.

Comment: Wow! So clever. $|g|=p_j^k M$, so $p_j (p_j^{k-1}Mg)=0$ and $|p_j^{k-1}Mg| $ divides $p_j$. It cannot be $1$ because that would contradict the order of $g$. Thanks. If you want to write your comment as an anwer I will accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comment to an answer:

The exponent is the LCM of all the element orders. A prime divides an LCM of numbers iff it divides (at least) one of those numbers. So some element has order a multiple of that prime, and you can simply power that element to get an element of order exactly that prime.